# Disable outlook ribbon button if one or more mails selected

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook add-in and I added a ribbon using visual designer with some controls like dropdown and submit button and textbox etc., On clicking the submit button I am selecting the selected mail subject and passing to service,

If more than one mail item is selected then I want to disable my button control. in which event I need to write the code to disable the button ?.

I tried this below code, this code is working on ribbon load but I want to call this method on mail item selection change. not sure how do I call the selection change event.

```
private bool IsMoreMailSelected()
{
        bool isSelected = false;
        outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.Selection mySelection = this.outlookObj.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
        int iCount = mySelection.Count;
        if (iCount > 1)
        {
            isSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSelected = false;
        }
        return isSelected;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle SelectionChange event in ThisAddin class, for example:

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer;        

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   
        currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(SelectionChangeEventHandler);
    }

    private void SelectionChangeEventHandler()
    {            
        bool buttonEnabled = false;
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1)
        {
            Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            buttonEnabled = selObject is Outlook.MailItem;                
        }
        Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.MyButton.Enabled = buttonEnabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813.aspx) event of the Explorer class where you can check how many items are selected. This event also occurs when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder. See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for the sample code.

In the event handler you can call the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate(v=office.14).aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol(v=office.14).aspx) methods of the IRibbonUI interface that allow to invalidates the cached value for controls (or a single control) on the Ribbon user interface. So, you will get the callbacks defined in the Ribbon XML markup invoked anew. See [Overview of the IRibbonUI Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) for more information.

In the `getEnabled` callback you just need to return false for disabling the control. The Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)